# What steps can troubleshoot OS X when some sites do not resolve on Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, internet, macos, network

I cannot access www.lubuntu.net from my Macbook Pro running OS X 10.6.8. I have an idea as to what the problem is (see *my opinion*), but I did all the usual things anyway (see *basic troubleshooting*), just to check.

*Basic Troubleshooting*

I can access almost any other site from my macbook (for example this one). I can access lubuntu.net from my other laptop which is on the same wifi, meaning it's not a network, ISP, or router issue. Also the site is up, and this issue is persistent for several days.

I can successfully ping the site. The site resolves to an IP (thus not a DNS issue). The problem occurs using three different browsers - Chrome, Firefox, Safari. I never use Safari, so it's not an extension issue, either. I cannot access the site even if I paste its IP into the address bar.

My IP is likely not banned, since (1) there is no reason to ban me and (2) my other laptop is able to access the site over the same network, going through the same router.

Rebooting does not solve the issue.

*My Opinion*

I installed (and quickly uninstalled) a program called PeerGuardian, which blocks "suspicious" IPs. It is mainly used for blocking unwanted peers when downloading torrents. I think that it messed with one of the config files to block the Lubuntu site.

Which files should I check? I've taken a look at /etc/hosts, and that looks fine. Also /etc/resolv.conf looks normal. No idea where to go from here.

**EDIT:** Here are the contents of system.log for my most recent attempt:

> Oct 18 21:44:11 albatross com.avast.proxy[50]: Error reading receive buffer: read(): Connection reset by peer
>
> Oct 18 21:45:20 albatross com.avast.proxy[50]: Defective HTTP request!
>
> Oct 18 21:45:20 albatross com.avast.proxy[50]: Unexpected AV CHECKURL response code (501)!
>
> Oct 18 21:46:24 albatross [0x0-0x165165].com.avast.AAFM[2093]: 18 Oct 21:46:24 ntpdate[2133]: no servers can be used, exiting
>
> Oct 18 21:46:27 albatross avast![2093]: event_master_disconnected
>
> Oct 18 21:46:38 albatross com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[322] (com.avast.helper): Throttling respawn: Will start in 5 seconds
>
> Oct 18 21:46:45 albatross com.avast.proxy[50]: Error reading receive buffer: read(): Connection reset by peer

Do you think this is a problem caused by Avast? But I installed avast after the problem started, because I thought it might be a virus, so that doesn't make much sense...

**EDIT 2:** added contents of /etc/hosts below

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.

127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost ::1             localhost
 fe80::1%lo0    localhost
```

Comment: Have you checked the various log files such as system.log?  The easiest way to check them is to run Console.app

Comment: Copied contents into question. albatross is the hostname

Comment: Can you also post the contents of `/etc/hosts`? I doubt its the issue since DNS resolves, but just curious.

Comment: I've posted /etc/hosts above. Everything seems typical, but not sure about last line.

Comment: PeerGuardian uses a kernel extension (.kext) to do its filtering, so if it's at fault, you wouldn't see anything different in /etc/hosts.  Yours looks fine.

Comment: Instead, see if you have an app called "pgstart" in "/Library/Application Support/PeerGuardian/".  If you do, try doing a "sudo ./pgstart -u" from that directory.  Then try heading to a "banned" site.  Also see if you have a /Library/Extensions/PeerGuardian.kext , and if so, move it to a temporary folder somewhere else and restart; if none of that works, try _installing_ PeerGuardian again using all default options and then running the uninstaller again.

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode by pressing Shift during startup (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533). Safe Mode does a lot of things (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564), among them it **loads only required kernel extensions**, so PeerGuardian's kext, if still installed on our system, won't be loaded. Then test if you can connect to www.lubuntu.net.

Comment: You're right that it's not a DNS issue if you can ping the site by its domain. Do you have an HTTP proxy set up (System Prefs > Network > Advanced)? What happens when you run `curl lubuntu.net` in terminal?

Comment: @jmk curl: (7) Failed to connect to 140.211.166.147: Connection refused

Comment: @jaume I can get onto Lubuntu in safe mode. So then it's PeerGuardian's fault, probably? And how do I fix it?

Comment: @strangelydim pgstart is not present. PeerGurdian.kext was not in /Library/Extensions, but was in /Library/Application Support/PeerGuardian/. I renamed it and moved it to /tmp, but it didn't help. I will try your method of re-installing and uninstalling.

Comment: And if instead of moving PeerGuardian.kext to /tmp you delete it (either with rm or moving the kext to the Trash and emptying it)?. If it worked in safe mode it's probably the kext, so let's get rid of it. Check also in System Preferences>Users & Groups>Login Items whether PeerGuardian is listed and remove it. Reboot and try to connect to lubuntu.

Comment: @jaume Everything is good after the reboot and removing the kext file. If you formulate that into an answer, you get the bounty. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In agreement with the original poster, in this answer I put together the comments above that describe the troubleshooting steps that helped solve the issue.

1. Realize that PeerGuardian uses a KEXT.

   As *strangelydim* commented, [PeerGuardian](http://sourceforge.net/projects/peerguardian/) (an open source privacy oriented firewall software) uses a [kernel extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Extend/Extend.html) (KEXT). The KEXT is used to block connections to "dangerous" servers specified in so-called blocklists.
2. Find out whether the KEXT was the culprit.

   The original poster booted his Mac into Safe Mode by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> during startup (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533).

   Safe Mode does a lot of things (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564), among them **it loads only required kernel extensions**, so PeerGuardian's KEXT wouldn't be loaded.

   The original poster could successfully connect to www.lubuntu.net, so the KEXT was the offender.
3. Disable the KEXT.

   The first try was to move the KEXT from `/Library/Application Support/PeerGuardian` to `/tmp` and reboot. That didn't help. The original poster then deleted the KEXT. I also asked him to check in `System Preferences>Users & Groups>Login Items` whether PeerGuardian was listed and remove it.

   After a reboot he could sucessfully connect to www.lubuntu.net.

So the bottom line is that, unfortunately, some programs cannot be uninstalled by simply dragging them to the Trash.

Answer (score 0):

I was also recently trying to fix the same issue and it came down to PeerGuardian. I just altered the settings but didn't remove it, but found this article about a program called AppDelete that mentioned PeerGuardian and a number of its files that it would leave behind if you simply removed from the Applications folder:

http://dailyblogged.com/2506/appdelete-uninstall-anything-seriously/

Maybe this can help you track down any remaining files that are causing issues with your machine.